# Word choice: "them" or " their"

Tags: pronouns

> I don't like _____ eating.

What will be better to use, *them* or *their*.
I want to say  *their way of eating* .But, i want to cut it short, according to context. 
Can I use the sentence this way, using '*them* or *their*.

Comment: I don't like **their** eating.  You can read [this](http://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/dealing-with-pronouns-and-gerunds/).

Comment: They mean different things. "their eating" refers to how they eat. "them eating" refers to the fact that they are eating.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean they slurp their soup, burp loudly, talk with their mouths full, and wipe their faces with their sleeves, you can say,

> I don't like their [table manners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_manners).